# iScroll not working in iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, iscroll

I already have an app. Im trying to integrate iScroll for faster scroll in iOS.

So created iScroll instance on the element having "overflow:auto" as specified in http://iscrolljs.com

Android has no issues. But iOS doesn't scroll at all.

Anything else do I need to do to let this work in iOS ?

Comment: I opened that link and the version of that library that you are using is so old that the warning doesn't even point to the current version. Maybe try using iScroll 5 instead of iScroll 1?...

Comment: Im using scroll5 itself. but steps are similar . Adding the instance of scroll

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I want to integrate into existing app

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer can help someone who is stuck with iScroll.

In the existing app, just check if there are any transitions already added on the element. As these will override the transition added by iScroll.

in iOS 10 scrolling is not smooth, use {'useTransition': false} for smooth scroll. But iOS 11 works fine without this.

These will be ignored sometimes.